# English equivalent for "matrimonial bed"

Tags: single-word-requests

I just heard that some romance languages (e.g., Spanish and Italian) use a word that translates directly as "matrimonial bed" and basically means a queen- or king- sized, as far as I can tell.

Does English have a parallel word? Was "matrimonial bed" ever used in English?

Comment: I think most folks in the US now would take the term to mean the bed of a newly-married couple.  Dunno about 100 years ago or so.  But king and queen size beds have only been around since 1960 or so.  Before that the largest common bed was the "full" size bed (though I vaguely recall some other term for a larger one).  To my recollection the "double" bed was smaller than "full".

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_size) gives standard bed sizes, though I don't believe it accounts for historical variations prior to 1950 or so.

Comment: (It should also be noted that the above Wiki article give sizes for other countries.)

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish, (and I suppose Italian) the matrimonial bed means a double bed. But it also is an image to refer to a couple's sexual relationship. In the metaphorical sense,one might see in English, marriage bed....

Comment: indeed that's what first came to mind when I heard the word used, but that was a flat mistake in context. The context in which the word was used was strictly and unambiguously about the size of a bed/mattress and the size alone.

Comment: @MichaelChirico - then in English you should use *king size* or *queen size* etc.

Comment: @Jim indeed I do... the appeal of "matrimonial bed" to me was that it seemed like a concise way to refer to a larger bed in general (queen or larger sounds verbose, "large bed" sounds nonspecific). It would appear there's no such parallel given the response so far